# Remove and replace column

Tags: shell, text-processing, columns, numeric-data

I have a file which looks like this:

```
1 1
2 5.24
3 12.46
4 21.56
```

and so on. I need to change it to:

```
1 1
3 5.24
5 12.46
7 21.56
```

on a quick way. So the first column has to have odd values `2i+1` for `i` going from `0` to the length of the column, instead of integers. Waht is the best way to do using a shell command?

Comment: Uncertain what you need.  How is the value of 7 for line `4 21.56` arrived at ?

Comment: ma first column is made of integers 1,2,3, and so on.  I want to remove that columns and replace it with odd integers 1,3,5,7,9 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly simple using Awk

```
$ awk '{$1 = 2*(NR-1)+1} 1' file
1 1
3 5.24
5 12.46
7 21.56
```

Comment: How can I also directly store the edited file? This is only giving me an output in the terminal

Comment: @Giacomo it depends - if you have a recent version of GNU Awk (`gawk`) you can add `-i inplace` to the command options. Otherwise, you will need to redirect to a temporary file and then rename it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
awk '{print NR++,$2}' file
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/uqAoM69EwS9IW1tHxaj2/39DBUMuIwVTPSMTLmMFQyM9EzMuEwUjQz1TMwA)

Or even

```
awk '{$1=NR++}1' file
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/WsXQ1i9IW7vW8P9/QwVDLiMFUz0jEy5jBUMjPRMzLhMFI0M9UzMA)